# R: Column Heading Conversions

Tags: r, csv, multiple-columns

I have the following dataset. My objective is to understand how numbers and mammals and birds are there in the two types of locations.

```
df1:

Location Type  Cat  Mouse Dog Chicken Turkey Horse
1              1    0     0   1       0      1  
1              0    0     1   0       1      0   
2              1    1     1   1       1      1 
2              0    1     0   0       0      0 
1              1    1     0   0       1      0
```

I want it to read as

```
df2:
Location Type  M    M     M   B       B      M
1              1    0     0   1       0      1  
1              0    0     1   0       1      0   
2              1    1     1   1       1      1 
2              0    1     0   0       0      0 
1              1    1     0   0       1      0
```

with 'M' denoting Mammal and 'B' denoting Bird

I tried to manually enter the data into my .csv file and use it in R, however, the file gets read as

```
df2:
 Location Type     M    M1    M2  B       B1     M3
    1              1    0     0   1       0      1  
    1              0    0     1   0       1      0   
    2              1    1     1   1       1      1 
    2              0    1     0   0       0      0 
    1              1    1     0   0       1      0
```

I am not sure why each 'M' or 'B' column gets numbered separately, how could I prevent this from happening

or

I also have the animal type classified as mammal and bird in another dataframe as below

```
dfanimal:    
Name of Animal Mammal/Bird
    Cat            Mammal
    Dog            Mammal
    Mouse          Mammal
    Chicken        Bird
    Turkey         Bird
    Horse          Mammal
```

If there is a way for me to directly work my way with the dataframes, df1 and dfanimal?

Would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you manually change the column names, you can use `check.names = FALSE` while importing the csv. Since it is not advised to have duplicate column names in the dataframe those suffixes are by default added by R.

```
df1 <- read.csv('location/of/file.csv', check.names = FALSE)
```

---

If you want to use `df_animal` to change the column names, we can use `match`

```
names(df1)[-1] <- substr(df_animal$Mammal.Bird[match(names(df1)[-1], 
                         df_animal$Name_of_Animal)], 1, 1)

df1
#  Location M M M B B M
#1        1 1 0 0 1 0 1
#2        1 0 0 1 0 1 0
#3        2 1 1 1 1 1 1
#4        2 0 1 0 0 0 0
#5        1 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Cat = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Mouse = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Dog = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), Chicken = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Turkey = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Horse = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df_animal <- structure(list(Name_of_Animal = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Cat", "Chicken", "Dog", "Horse", "Mouse", "Turkey"
), class = "factor"), Mammal.Bird = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bird", "Mammal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```